# Building/deploying a EJB .jar with its dependencies

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jar, jboss, ejb

I am new to Java EE. I use Maven, Eclipse and jBoss/WildFly.

I have a `war` project. When I build the project all its dependencies are packaged inside the `war` file in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Now I am trying to create a `ejb` project (I have `<packaging>ejb</packaging>` in the `pom.xml`). I want to deploy it as a separate project (not as a part of the `war`). When I build the `ejb` project Maven does not package any dependencies in the `jar`.

How can I package/deploy a `ejb` `.jar` **with its dependencies**?

**UPDATE:** I'd like to avoid packaging EJBs in an `.ear` if it is possible. (I do not want to create one more Maven project).

Comment: If you are in Java EE an EJB should be packaged into the EAR file which also contains the WAR file.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your reply! I know that I can package my `EJB` `.jar` into an `.ear`. But I do not want to create an additional Maven project (`.ear`). I'd like to deploy my `EJB` `.jar` independently if it is possible. My `.war` is a separate project that will be deployed as a separate application in any case.

Comment: Are you using remote ejb`s ? If no you can't deploy it separately in JEE...In such cases the usual approache is to create a multi module build which contains the ejb, war and ear...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, I use remote EJB interfaces.

Comment: Than you can create ejb client via maven-ejb-plugin? But the server part of the ejb must be in EAR file in combination with WAR...

Comment: @khmarbaise The `.war` will be a client that will use the remote EJBs. And I want to package EJBs into a `.jar`. I have `<packaging>ejb</packaging>` in the `pom.xml` and Maven invokes `maven-ejb-plugin` when it builds the project (I can see it in the Maven log). But Maven does not package any dependencies in the `.jar`. This is my problem.

Comment: @Alex, any luck? The chosen answer seems to indicate that packaging the dependencies in the EJB jar is bad design, but it seems much more straight-forward to me. Did you end up packaging in an EAR?

Comment: @Alex, necrobumping here, but face the same problem, how did you solve the problem exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is package your project as ear. But if don't want use ear, maven assembly plugin can help you to package all needed jars in one file. This solution is only for "proof of concept" variant, and cannot be used in production mode, by licences limitation for example.

Comment: Are you able to say why this is the best solution?

Comment: Because packaging artifacts in ear is the one legal way of gathering artifacts in same archive in JavaEE ecosystem. Another solutions looks like workarounds. Other commentors mentioned the same thought higher.