Liberty - EJB - bean does not have a public constructor that does not take parameters & java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
I am trying to migrate from IBM Websphere Traditional server to IBM liberty.

IBM Websphere Traditional : 8.5.5.21 ->
Liberty Version : 23.0.0.12, Product Edition:Base

I Am facing the Error below
    [ERROR   ] CNTR5007E: The UserInfoBean enterprise bean in the Ejb.jar module of the EAR application failed to start. Exception: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: EJB class com.app.sam.ejb.UserInfoBean must have a public constructor that takes no parameters: EAR#Ejb.jar#UserInfoBean
        at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.jitdeploy.EJBUtils.validateEjbClass(EJBUtils.java:348)
    at [internal classes]
at javax.naming.InitialContext. lookup(InitialContext. java:428)
        ...  more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.app.sam.domain.Information
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:291)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
        at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.jitdeploy.EJBUtils.validateEjbClass(EJBUtils.java:341)
        ... 1 more

Server.xml:

ejbLite-3.1 jaxb-2.2 jdbc-4.0 jndi-1.0 jpa-2.0 json-1.1 jsp-2.2
servlet-3.0 jaxws-2.2

Here is my project structure:

Ear
War
Domain
Delegate
Ejb

EAR:
<plugins>
<plugin>
<artifactId›maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.10‹/version>
<configuration>
<version>6</version›
<defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir›

War:
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactld>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
    <archive>
    <manifest>
    <addclasspath>true</addClasspath>
    </manifests>
    <manifestEntries>
    <Class-Path>domain-jar Ejb.jar delegate.jar</Class-Path›
    </manifestEntries>
    </archives>
    </configurations>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>

EJB:
‹build›
<plugins>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-ejb-pluginc/artifactId>
<version›2.5</version>
<configuration>
<ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
<archive> <manifest>
<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
</manifest> 
</archive>
</configuration>
</plugins>

Trying to migrate from ibm websphere traditional to liberty
EAR.ear ---lib --- all the required jar are here 
        ---war.jar
        ---ejb.jar
        ---delegate.jar
        ---domain.jar


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156115/maven-ejb-packaging-with-dependent-libraries

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156115/maven-ejb-packaging-with-dependent-libraries

Have same error as above but my app was ejb with jpa

You referenced the other questions which seem to be related to packaging via the maven ear and ejb plugins.  Maybe post the relevant snippets of pom.xml including at least the configuration of those two plugins in the various modules.

@ScottKurz please take a look added more details as requested

When an EJB is started, the EJB container will attempt to obtain the EJB implementation constructor.  If that fails for any reason, the CNTR5007E is reported.  Likely there is a valid constructor, but the class could not be loaded because of missing dependency... in this case : com.app.sam.domain.Information.  In order to resolve this, the com.app.sam.domain.Information class needs to be packaged either in the EJB JAR module, or a JAR module in the "lib" directory of the EAR, or configured as a module in a shared classloader associated with the application.

So can you please take a look and see where the 'com.app.sam.domain.Information' is packaged?

Yes domain.jar was packaged in EAR.ear and  domain.jar as dependency in EJB pom @Tracy

When domain.jar is packaged in the EAR.ear, is it placed in the "lib" directory? Declaring it in the EJB pom is needed for Maven and helpful in an IDE, but I don't believe the Liberty runtime uses that. pom is strictly for build. The Liberty runtime will create a classloader with the EJB JAR modules and other JARs located in the "lib" directory (default behavior). If domain.jar is at the root of the EAR and is not also an EJB module, it would be ignored by Liberty.

domain.jar is pacakaged in root not in lib folder of EAR.ear.
i have updated with the ear packaging structure.

So were you able to try moving domain.jar to the EAR 'lib' directory to see if that fixed the problem?
